# Campo búsqueda activo al cargar página

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo el problema que al cargar la página se queda el cursor en el campo "búsqueda" y me gustaría que al cargar la misma no se activase ese campo al menos que se le hiciese click en el mismo. He probado a quitarle rerady de $(document).ready(function() pero sigue igual:

```
<form class="search">
   <input type="text" id="busqueda" class="search__input" placeholder="Search for students & cells..." autocomplete="off" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.0.0" spellcheck="false" dir="auto">
   <i style="position:absolute; z-index:1" class="zwicon-search search__helper" data-sa-action="search-close"></i>
   <i class="zwicon-arrow-left search__reset"></i>
   <div id="resultado" class="search__inner"></div>
</form>

        $(function() {
    var consulta;
    //hacemos focus al campo de búsqueda
    //$("#busqueda").blur();

    //comprobamos si se pulsa una tecla
    $("#busqueda").keyup(function(e){

          //obtenemos el texto introducido en el campo de búsqueda
          consulta = $("#busqueda").val();
          //hace la búsqueda                                                                                  
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "buscar_todo.php",
                data: "b="+consulta,
                dataType: "html",
                beforeSend: function(){
                //imagen de carga
                $("#resultado").html("<p align='center'><img src='images/loader.gif' width='20px' /></p>");
                },
                error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
                },
                success: function(data){                                                    
                $("#resultado").empty();
                $("#resultado").append(data);                                                             
                }
          });                                                                         
    });                                                     
});
```

Comment: Pero el cursor te va al campo porque le estás dando el foco con esta línea:
$("#busqueda").focus();
¿O te refieres a otra cosa?

Comment: Incluso quitándole el focus se queda el cursor en el campo search

Answer (score 0):

Yo igualmente quitaría la linea de $("#busqueda").focus().

Deberías usar .blur() en tu $(document).ready()

`El .blur() se envía a un elemento para que pierda el foco. Originalmente, este evento solo era aplicable a elementos de formulario, como <input>. En navegadores recientes, el dominio del evento se ha extendido para incluir todos los tipos de elementos. Un elemento puede perder el foco a través de los comandos del teclado, como la tecla Tab, o al hacer clic con el mouse en otra parte de la página.`

Entonces, sustituye la linea del .focus() y pon .blur(), para que quede así:

```
$("#busqueda").blur();
```

Pongo el código de ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#busqueda").blur();
});
```

```html
<form class="search">
    <input type="text" id="busqueda" class="search__input" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.0.0" spellcheck="false" dir="auto">
 </form>
```

Y aquí el resultante, sin el foco:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: inlcuso con blur() sigue el campo activo. Si le pincho en cualquier otro lado se desactiva

Comment: He editado con el ejemplo, fijate que a mi no me pone el foco encima...

Comment: Me lo sigue poniendo como activo... increible pero no sé que es lo que hay mal en mi código...

Comment: Bueno, igual el problema es que no hay ningún otro elemento al que desviarle el foco, puesto que es el único input que existe en el form

Comment: He editado el código que hay más arriba y es lo que tengo puesto ahora mismo. No sé que pasa pero me sigue poniendo el foco en el input ese...